# Trouble implementing generic Timer Class using boost::asio::deadline_timer

Tags: c++, boost

Implementing a timer class on a UI application.

Basically the problem I have is that calling `io.run()` would block, rendering the `async_wait` call useless. From reading other posts I got the impression that somehow Timer, or at least the code that calls `startCountdown`, should be on another thread.

Below is my code. How do I manage this in a way that is considered correct in Boost?

```
class Timer
{
public:

    Timer() : countdownTimer(io) {  }

    void startCountdown(int seconds)
    {
        countdownTimer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(seconds));
        countdownTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Timer::on_timeout, this, _1));
        io.run(); // this blocks
    }

    void on_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& e)
    {
        if (e != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            cout << "Timer expired!";
        }
    }

private:

    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer countdownTimer;
}
```

Comment: Depends, but as a rough estimate you need to have its own thread for the io-service.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call the `run` member function of `io_service` but rahter one of :

- [run_one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run_one.html)
- [poll](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll/overload1.html)
- [poll_one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll/overload1.html)

Depending on your design goal.

Also note that `boost Asio` is not really designed to be a secondary library to use for some features but rather as a core element of your program, it is more a spine than an arm.

A thread dedicated to handle everything linked to the io_service could also work, but good luck synchronizing shared data between a synchronous and an asynchronous world :)

Comment: For a simple Timer, though, are there better alternatives? I ended up moving the code in `startCountdown` to a different thread, and that seemed to work.

Comment: @AldrichCo AFAIK if you want to use `asio`'s timers asynchronously you will necessarily have an `io_service` running somewhere and if it is not a part of your application core structure i guess it has to be in the background.